# C : Extracting sentences extended to next line

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file in which on each line there are multiple sentences separated by white spaces. SOmetimes one sentence may extend to next line. I want to extract these sentences separated by white space. My code successfully extracts sentences on same line separated by white space but since it is reading line by line. SO, issue comes when one sentence is extended to next line.

Comment: Why don't you open the file in binary mode (e.g. `rb`) and read it that way? You can read char by char and simply ignore newlines or something.

Answer (score 1):

Store the part unused in creation of line at each iteration in temperary buffer. Include the buffer in the next iteration (append at the begining of line read).